# Gerrit Update Patch to Latest Code

Tags: git, gerrit

How do I update my patch on gerrit to latest code without making any merge commits? My patch is a few commits behind and I don't want to make a new patch on gerrit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Works and will fix conflicts when needed.